# Android best way to get small external data

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

I have to get some external data. Long story short - it's a string array for a autocomplete field. I did it with a `AsyncTask` in my `Activity`. Everything works fine, I just get file from external server, put it into a String array and attach to my autocomplete field:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
    result);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editCity);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is I do it every time I go to the specific `Activity`. Every time the `AsyncTask` is launched, and it sometimes slows my app a little bit. What is a better way to get that data only once and then keep it for entire app lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a static reference for your data, that way you will ensure it will stay there as long as the VM is running.

you can create a class and call it something like `DataStorage` and inside that class add a static ArrayAdapter object

```
public class DataStorage{
  public static ArrayAdapter<String> sharedData;
}
```

and from anywhere in your code whenever you want to load that adapter:

```
if (DataStorage.sharedData == null){
     // write code to set sharedData
}
```

This is called Singleton pattern , you can read more about it here : [Singleton Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this data once and then store it in your `Application` class of your app.
so the next time you turn on this `Activity` check first if the array in your application
class is not empty and dont run the `AsyncTask`.

To add an Application class to your application do this:

**1.** create a class that extends Application like this:

```
public class YourApplicationClass extends Application
{   
    ....
}
```

**2.** and in your manifast define it as your application class like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".YourApplicationClass"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    ....
```

This class is accessible for all the other Activity class in your application.

**Documentation:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html